# grails cf-info gives null pointer exception

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I just installed the cloud foundry plugin with the compile directive as detailed in the documentation. Also, as detailed in the documentation, I put in my username, and password in the ~/.grails/settings.groovy file. For good measure, I also exited out of the terminal and restarted that (and then the machine). However I get the following error when I type in grails cf-info It gives me the following :

|`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.login(CloudFoundryClient.java:211)
    at ClientWrapper.methodMissing(_CfCommon_groovy:536)
    at _CfCommon_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_CfCommon_groovy:110)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at CfInfo$_run_closure1.doCall(CfInfo:33)`

As an FYI: I have the following in my BuildConfig.groovy :

```
`compile ':cloud-foundry:1.2.3'  
 compile ':webxml:1.4.1'`
```

And my grails version is 2.3.1

Thanks a million for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Foundry Grails plugin has not been updated for CF v2 yet. You should use the "cf" CLI for pushing Grails apps.

See http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/managing-apps/cf/index.html and http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/jvm/index.html.